# insert picture at the top of tabular

Tags: tikz-pgf

Insert Picture A at the top Left of the cell, then insert Picture B at the center of the cell (or move it from center by 5pt), I am not good using tikz, please example why you are using specific code in order to understand

```
\documentclass[20pt,twoside]{report}

\usepackage{graphicx}


\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tabularx}


\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\linewidth}
Hello
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.55\linewidth}

\begin{tabularx}{0.9\linewidth}{|X|X|X|}
    \hline
\includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{example-image-b}
& item 13 & item 21  \\

\hline
\end{tabularx}

    
\end{minipage}  


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you please include a sketch of the desired output? What exactly does "Picture B at the center of the cell" mean here? (Do you refer to the horizontal or vertical center of the cell?) How do you want to align the texts in the other two columns with respect to the images? Please clarify. Since you mentioned `tikz`, how is this related to tikz? You load it but don't use it in your example code.

Comment: Entirely unrelated to the question, but since you added `20pt` as an option for the `report` class: Please keep in mind that the standard classes only offer `10pt`, `11pt` and `12pt` as options regarding base font sizes. (Therefore you also get the warning message: "Unused global option(s): [20pt].".) If you nevertheless want a `20pt` base font size, you might want to replace `report` with `extreport`. (The latter offers base font sizes from 8 to 20pt.)

Comment: \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={inner sep=0,outer sep=0}]
 \node (a) [anchor=north] {\includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{example-image-a}};
 \node (b) [below left] {\includegraphics[scale=0.08]{example-image-b}};  
\end{tikzpicture}
I am trying to understand the package of tikz

Comment: Is this the output you would like to get? https://i.stack.imgur.com/egyKT.png

Comment: @leandriis yes this is what i am looking for. thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[twoside]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\linewidth}
Hello
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.55\linewidth}

\begin{tabularx}{0.9\linewidth}{|l|X|X|}
    \hline%
\tikz[baseline=(Cats-1-1.base)]{
\matrix[matrix of nodes, nodes={inner sep=0pt},ampersand replacement=\&] (Cats){
\includegraphics[width=.15\textwidth]{example-image-a} \& \\
                                                       \& \includegraphics[width=.07\textwidth]{example-image-b} \\};}
& item 13 & item 21  \\

\hline
\end{tabularx}
  
\end{minipage}  


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you explain the matrix of nodes code, in order to understand

Comment: In very simple terms is another table. Therefore with `\matrix` I've create another small table inside the first cell of the other table. You can find how to use `\matrix` in the [PGFmanual](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgf).