# Aligning Tikz drawing inside table cell

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, alignment

```
\documentclass[a5paper,]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
 % \usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcolumntype{L}{>{$} m{1in}<{$}}

\newcommand{\myvector}{
\begin{vmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13}\\
a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23}\\
a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33}\\
\end{vmatrix}}

\newcommand{\mybox}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{| L | L | L |}
    \toprule[1.5pt]
    \myvector &  & \myvector \\ \midrule
    \myvector & \mybox & \myvector \\ \midrule
    \myvector & & \myvector \\
    \bottomrule[1.5pt]
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

which outputs:

[image]

(1) Why does Tikz drawing causing extra vertical space? (Note that in the second row things are pushed down.)

(2) Is there a way to “find my way” inside the table cell with respect to Tikz coordinates? For example, how do I draw the same drawing from the right bottom to the left up; or center it both horizontally and vertically inside the cell?

Comment: Similar question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/574837/162128).

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** it seems that in the first try I misunderstood the question. Hopefully that now I'm on the right track ...

[image]

You need to change baseline of `tikz` image:

```
\documentclass[a5paper,]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array, makecell}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{hyperref}% had to be load last


\newcommand{\myvector}{
\begin{vmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13}\\
a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23}\\
a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33}\\
\end{vmatrix}}


\tikzset{TN/.style = {% Table's Nodes style
    baseline=(current bounding box.center),
    node distance = 0mm,
         M/.style = {minimum size=##1, inner sep=0pt},
    N/.style args = {##1/##2}{draw=##1, minimum size=##2, inner sep=2pt,
                              align=center},
            }}  


\begin{document}
\[
\setcellgapes{5pt}
\makegapedcells
\begin{array}{| c | c | c |}
    \Xhline{1.2pt}
    \myvector & \tikz[TN]{
                \node (n) [M=22mm]    {};
                \node[N=red/3mm,  above  left=of n.south east] {south\\east};
                          }          
                        & \myvector \\ \hline
    \myvector & \tikz[TN]{
                \node (n) [N=none/22mm, fill=gray!50]    {};
                \node[N=red/3mm,  above  left=of n.south east] {};
                \node[N=blue/3mm, below right=of n.north west] {};
                \node[N=white/8mm] {};
                \node[N=yellow/6mm, fill=yellow,
                      above right=6mm of n.south west] {}
                         }  
                        & \myvector \\ \hline
    \myvector & \tikz[TN]{
                \node[N=black/12mm] {center};
                          }
                        & \myvector \\
    \Xhline{1.2pt}
\end{array}
\]

\[
\setcellgapes{5pt}
\makegapedcells
\begin{array}{| c | c | c |}
    \Xhline{1.2pt}
    \myvector & \tikz[TN]{
                \node[N=black/12mm] {center};
                          }
                        & \myvector \\
    \Xhline{1.2pt}
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

*Note*: macro `\makegapedcells` doesn't work iif in table are `m` column types

Comment: @blackened, because I by accident delete`\tikzlibrary{positioning}` in preamble. I will correct this asap.

Comment: @blackened, MWE is corrected now. Sorry for any inconvenience.

Comment: Okay, I am removing my comment, including this one.